# Accessing and importing data from a private CSV file using os.path.join(...)

Tags: web2py

I have a CSV file in my private files that i am trying to read & import information from but i get **None** values, below is my import controller code, am i doing something wrong?

**CSV IMPORT CONTROLLER:**

```
import os
def viewInfo():
db = DAL('sqlite:memory')
db.define_table('Clients',
                     Field('Name'),
                     Field('Surname'))
backfile = os.path.join(request.folder,'private', 'Client_Bookings_Backup.csv')
db.Clients.import_from_csv_file(open(backfile))
grid = SQLFORM.grid(db.Clients, args=[db.Clients], editable=False, deletable=False, user_signature=False)
return locals()
```

Regards:

Mostwanted

Comment: What are the file headers?

Comment: Oh Ok! guess what! My field headers in my database table were different from the ones i defined here in my controller! The ones in my db table started with small letters where as the ones in my controller started with capital letters but when i matched them it worked, now it can import actual values. Thanks Tony

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Anthony i was able to figure out that my table headers in my model db differed from the the table headers in my controller function defined db. The headers in my model db started with small letters where as the ones in controller function started with capital letters but as soon as I matched the headers in both the model db table and the controller function db I was able to import from the CSV file.

**MODEL:**

```
db.define_table('person',
            Field('name'),
            Field('surname'))
```

**CSV IMPORT CONTROLLER:**

```
def viewInfo():
db = DAL('sqlite:memory')
db.define_table('Clients',
                Field('name'),
                Field('surname'))
backfile = os.path.join(current.request.folder,'private', 'Client_Bookings_Backup.csv')
db.Clients.import_from_csv_file(open(backfile))
grid = SQLFORM.grid(db.Clients, args=[db.Clients], editable=False, deletable=False, user_signature=False)
return locals()
```

Thanks again Tony

Regards:

Mostwanted